# How can a web page find what value to POST?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I'm currently making an application for a client to automatically fill some web forms on the website he uses to store his item pricing. The website doesn't have a documented public API, and there doesn't seem to be a way to add bulk pricing on the website itself. In order to accomplish this, I'm making a simple python application that reads his data, then sends `POST`s to the website.

Their website is giving me a hard time, however, because it's sending payloads containing dozens of fields, while the form used to enter the pricing information only has 4 input fields. On top of that, their website uses `angularjs` to generate most of the web page, so I can't just find the `<form>[...]</form>` block and look at what's being sent, because that's not what they use.

Here is what the payload json looks like:

```
{
"entities":
    [
        {
            "Price_Line_ID":"{}",
            "Price_List_ID":"{}",
            "Item_ID":"{}",
            "Uofm_ID":"{}",
            "Amount":"{}",
            "Dtstamp":"{}",
            "Tenant_ID":"{}",

            "Created_On":"null",
            "Created_By":"null",
            "Changed_On":"null",
            "Changed_By":"null",
            "Seq":"0",
            "Begin_Qty":"0",
            "End_Qty":"0",
            "Customer_ID":"null",
            "Tax_Before_Discount":"false",
            "Discount_Target":"All",
            "Max_Discount_Amount":"null",
            "Min_Discount_Amount":"null",
            "Customer_Name":"null",
            "Uofm":"null",
            "Item_Number":"null",
            "Uofm_Schedule_ID":"null",
            "Uofm_Schedule":"null",
            "Inactive":"false",
            "entityAspect":
            {
                "entityTypeName":"PriceLine:#SalesPad.Spo.Api.Model",
                "defaultResourceName":"PriceLines",
                "entityState":"Added",
                "originalValuesMap":
                {},
                "autoGeneratedKey":
                {
                    "propertyName":"Price_Line_ID",
                    "autoGeneratedKeyType":"Identity"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "saveOptions":
    {}
}
```

The 7 values at the top (with values of "{}") are found when I do a `GET` or `POST` action on the website's other pages. I've managed to find where all the values originate from, except the "Price_Line_ID" one, because it appears to change from page to page (and it changes after a price is added).

I know a web page can get the data needed for a `POST` event either in its own html (when using tags like `<form>`), and it can get them from other `GET` and `POST` events. Is there any other way for a web page to determine a value that will be sent in a `POST` event?

I'm not very familiar with `angularjs`, although from what I understand it only creates a bunch of Javascript for the page. Does it offer different ways of determining what values are sent in a `POST` or `GET` event?

**Edit:** I've already tracked all responses from `GET` and `POST` events from logging-in to adding a price, the `Price_Line_ID` field changes from page to page, and adding the price appears to use an ID different to the one received in the `GET` event. I just want to know the different ways that a web page (specifically one using `angularjs` might use to determine the value of the data sent in `POST` events.

Comment: If you are able to access your client's site and update some prices as a test, you could use a tool like Fiddler to intercept and examine the contents of the requests/responses that occur.  But the easiest way would be to get a copy of the API reference for (SalesPad?) from somewhere.

Comment: That's how I got the payload data. I went from the login page to the add event with chrome's network tab open and I can't find where it's coming from. It'll be `foo` on one page and `bar` on another. Which is annoying because it doesn't appear to be modified by any other `GET` or `POST` event.